# Get application base URL .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using this code to get the application base URL,

```
            StringValues requestOriginStrings;
            string url = "";
            var found = Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin", out requestOriginStrings);
            if (found)
            {
                url = requestOriginStrings.FirstOrDefault() + "/sendpassword/";
            }
```

Thsi works in localhost but not after deployment,

because the application link has two slashes :http://Domain/AppName , and so i get only "Domain" but not "Domain/AppName"

How can i get the AppName?

Any help? and Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> get the application base URL

If you'd like to get root URL of the website, you can try:

```
url = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Url.Content("~/")}";
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: This can help me get the BackEnd URL (.net core ) and not the FrontEnd Url (Angular). Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution FrontEnd side (angular) :

```
this.appUrl = location.pathname;
    this.appUrlSplitted = this.appUrl.split('/');
    this.appName = this.appUrlSplitted[1];
```

Comment: The question should be tagged as Angular then, not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: i wanted an .net core solution directly, i didn't want to use it FrontSide but yes